# I am new with c my program is running but nothing as an output

Tags: c

I am trying to learn c from a book but I am confused
I did the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) 
{
    int metrisi=getchar();
    putchar (metrisi);
    float proi=(metrisi-80)/40*1.5;
    float apog=(metrisi-80)/40*1.4;
    float brady=(metrisi-80)/40*1.4;
    {
        printf("%5.0f %5.0f %5.0f\n",  proi,apog,brady);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
C Online Compiler [gcc-6.3]
Copyright (c) Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Compiling your program...
Build completed successfully!
Running your program...

\xff...
The program executed successfully!
```

Could you please help me? No input from the user, no output.
Thank you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185243/discussion-on-question-by-taniuki-i-am-new-with-c-my-program-is-running-but-noth).

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

```
int metrisi=getchar();
```

This will place the **ASCII value** of the **first** letter you type into metrisi.

You can get the decimal value of that by substracting 48, but that is quite unsafe - what happens if you input anthing other than a digit?

EDIT: As David pointed out, that substraction is technically not unsafe. However, since you want to do some arithmetic on your input values, it would be wise to make sure you only accept numbers as input.

Anyhow, the next problem is in your printf:

```
printf("%5.0f %5.0f %5.0f\n",  proi,apog,brady);
```

Here you specify to output 5 digits to the left of the decimal point, and 0 digits after the decimal point. Maybe you wanted this:

```
printf("%.5f %.5f %.5f\n",  proi,apog,brady);
```

There also is (my guess) a problem here:

```
float proi=(metrisi-80)/40*1.5;
```

This expression might yield quite surprising results. The reason for that is that there is something called [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) in C, and it is not always intuitive.

You could try this instead:

```
float proi=(metrisi-80)/(float)40*1.5;
```

or

```
float proi=(metrisi-80)/40.0*1.5;
```

Comment: Well, subtracting `'0'` (48) from the character value isn't really "unsafe". (in fact it is standard practice in many conversions). Before doing so you would want to check `if (isdigit(metrisi))` or the equivalent `if ('0' <= metrisi && metrisi <= '9')`. Another option for the `%5.0f` would be `%g` or `%5g` -- but it is unclear what the OP was attempting. A more interesting issue is the *integer division* result of `(metrisi-80)/40`. if `80 <= metrisi && metrisi <= 120` the result will be zero and `metrisi < 80` results in a negative value.

Comment: @David C. Rankin Yes, you are right. Subtracting 48 by and in itself is not technically unsafe, but most certainly would need an input check as you proposed. Of course we don't know the intentions of the programmer...but an (educated) guess on that.